# How to specify an empty id.vars vector when melting a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I'd like to melt a data.table without including any ID columns.

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(iris)[1:10]
data.table::melt(dt, measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'))
```

Without specifying id.vars, all of the non measure.vars columns are treated as id.vars.  This can be dealt with after the fact by only selecting variable/value from the melt.

For example, the below code produces the output I'm looking for:

```
data.table::melt(dt, measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'))[,.(variable, value)]
```

But I would have thought it should be possible within the melt call itself?  I've tried the below with no success.

```
data.table::melt(dt, measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'), id.vars=NULL)
data.table::melt(dt, measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'), id.vars=c())
data.table::melt(dt, measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'), id.vars=list())
```

From the documentation:

> If id.vars and measure.vars are both missing, all
>   non-numeric/integer/logical columns are assigned as id variables and
>   the rest as measure variables. If only one of id.vars or measure.vars
>   is supplied, the rest of the columns will be assigned to the other.
>   Both id.vars and measure.vars can have the same column more than once
>   and the same column can be both as id and measure variables.
>
> melt.data.table also accepts list columns for both id and measure
>   variables.

Answer (score 7):

`c()` and `NULL` are identical (e.g. `identical(c(), NULL) == TRUE`), and `NULL` is the value assigned internally to `id.vars` when it is missing.

However, an empty integer or character vector will do the trick:

```
data.table::melt(dt, measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'), id.vars=integer())
data.table::melt(dt, measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'), id.vars=character())
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can subset the columns before `melt`:

```
melt(dt[, c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')], measure.vars=c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'))
```